# Past Subscription Failed in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have some SSRS Report which is getting failed in past from sometime,  can we get 
detail for how many days the specific report got failed in the past. i did email subscription for that report

Can anyone please suggest.

Comment: Is the report being emailed to a number of recipients? If these recipients are listed as individuals (i.e. not in groups) then the SSRS report will fail if any one of those recipients have been deleted from the address book.

Comment: but none of the recipients have been deleted. i am trying to know on which all specific date, report has been failed. is there any way to know this information. Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help. This SQL runs on the ReportServer database and provides details on when a particular report ran ... (replace 'foo' with your report name obvs!)

```
SELECT ex.UserName, ex.Format, ex.TimeStart, cat.Name, ex.Parameters, 
CONVERT(nvarchar(10), ex.TimeStart, 101) AS rundate FROM 
ReportServer.DBO.ExecutionLog AS ex, Catalog AS cat 
where ex.ReportID = cat.ItemID
and name = 'foo'
ORDER BY rundate desc
```

Comment: Thanks. but i am not looking for report ran on a particular day,  i am trying to get when a particular report **not ran**. kindly suggest.

Comment: Hi @Shan. If the report runs on a once a day subscription then won't the SQL log give you an indication when it failed to run as there won't be an entry for that day?